# Use rabbitmq in Ubuntu 16.04 inside Docker

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker. I want to create an image in Docker which to run a microservice that needs RabbitMQ and Redis. For Redis, I include redis in the line `RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip libsasl2-dev libmysqlclient-dev redis-server wget` inside `Dockerfile`. To install RabbitMQ, I use

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y -q --allow-unauthenticated install rabbitmq-server
RUN /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
RUN echo "[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}]." > 
/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
# Port to expose
EXPOSE 9060 5672 15672
```

However, the rabbitmq server is not running in default which will prompt error when I run the built image. I have a line `ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]` to run my microservice. How can I run the rabbitMQ service from Dockerfile?

Comment: Sorry, but you does not understand proper docker way.You need to separate each service (like redis, rabbit, your app) to  
individual container and you can use official docker images for redis and rabbit. You can orchestrate them by docker-compose. This is docker way.

Comment: Ok will dive into it.

Comment: Docker is designed to run a single process per container. So when you are thinking about running multiple programs in a single image that's often a sign that you are working against Docker's conventions. Sometimes there are good reasons to do it, but in most cases you should do what @BukharovSergey said and go with orchestration of services.